# How to generate certain length Credit Card number with prefix?

Tags: python, random, while-loop, credit-card

Trying to generate a certain length credit card number with a prefix given.

```
    while len(str(cc_number)) < (len(str(length)) - 1):
        digit = str(random.randrange(0, 9))
        cc_number = str(cc_number) + str((digit))
        return cc_number
```

I'm expecting to get say 16 digits long number with a variable size prefix given. How do i make this piece of code generate a right size string of numbers? This code by the way only concatenates 1 random digit to the end of the string... So i expect to get '4349578451278456', but the actual output is '41'

Comment: `ccnumber + ''.join(random.choices(string.digits, k=16-length(ccnumber)))`

Comment: Also, Beware that not all 16 digits long numbers are valid credit card numbers. The number should comply to the Luhn algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm) to be considered a valid CC number

Comment: Yes, i know. Luhn algorithm wasn't a problem for me. It's this part that wrecked my head. Spent few hours to fix  a problem.. 1 second 'Shift + TAB' problem..

Answer (score 0):

If length is 16, `str(length)` will give you the string '16' which has a `len` of 2. Just use `length` without len or str.

Beyond that, your return statement should be outside of the loop

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using the `random` module, I just want to offer an alternative solution:

```
from random import choices
from string import digits

cc_digits = choices(digits, k=16)
cc_number = "".join(cc_digits)

print(cc_number)
```